# Fazer upload de ficheiro entre API's Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Olá,

Tenho uma API em nodejs, e preciso de enviar um ficheiro para uma outra API. Alguém sabe como posso reencaminhar o pedido?

Estou a usar o `https.request` (https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) para fazer o segundo pedido, e recebo o ficheiro em `req.files.file`.